# javascript scrolling multiple divs

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, unbind

```
    <script>
    $(document).ready(function() {

            $('#scrollingtext').bind('marquee', function() {
                var ob = $(this);
                var tw = ob.width();
                var ww = ob.parent().width();
                ob.css({ right: -tw });
                ob.animate({ right: ww }, 20000, 'linear', function() {
                    ob.trigger('marquee');

                });
            }).trigger('marquee');

        });     


    </script>

<div id="scrollingtext"></div>
```

i am doing foreach with this scrollingtext div so second time it does not scroll bec. of same id.. i tried some `$(this).unbind();` thing but could not solve it..  i need to scroll every id=scrollingtext inside foreach any help may save my hours..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

HTML only allows a single ID on the same page. Use a class instead. Problem solved.

```
<div class="scrollingtext"></div>
<div class="scrollingtext"></div>
<div class="scrollingtext"></div>
<script>
    $('.scrollingtext').bind('marquee', function() { /* .. */ });
</script>
```